# Interpreting uptime and top average load numbers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lamp

I am running a LAMP stack on an 8 core VPS (on Digital Ocean).
I am seeing extremely high load average numbers (in the 150 range - see below), while the server does not seem to be overloaded at all (it's quite responsive).
From what I understand, a load average of about 8 on an 8 core machine means that it is running at all its capacity.
Hence, how to interpret such high numbers that I am seeing?

[image]

Comment: The usual suspect is high disk usage when CPU/RAM are normal. What does the `iotop` output look like? (You may have to install this)

Comment: Based off of the results of top there. I'm going to say you have a particular task(s) pinned to a specific processor.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Like someone went crazy with `taskset`/`numactl`?

Comment: when you execute the command `top`, hit `1` to see the load of each CPU